# Rails Datatables with Ajax not working with Turbolink

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, datatables, turbolinks

So I have a new Rails 4 App using foundation and I started to integrate DataTables today and ran into one minor setback after setting it up to page using ajax calls.

When I click a link from one page (home in this instance) that sends me to a page that contains the datatables, the tables render without any entries or search box or pagination etc. However, if I refresh my browser, the page will fully refresh and the ajax call is made and the the table populates correctly.

After looking at the network traffic, I'm seeing that after clicking the link the response is 304: Not Modified. Since none of the other requests for the JS and CSS and etc, I'm assuming that the JS doesn't reload and make the proper ('#tasks').dataTable({...}) call.

Also, one thing to note is that the table is residing within a partial 'tasks_index.html.haml'.

One thing I did remember however was that I was still using the Turbolinks gem. I tried disabling it to see if that would fix my problem and surprisingly enough, it did.

So what would cause Turbolinks to prevent normal javascript to load on the page? Is there any way to force turbolinks to always load certain pages? Am I better off not even using Turbolinks?

Comment: In case someone else has this problem, I seem to have found a way to at least prevent turbolinks from getting in the way on a single link by applying an html tag 'data-no-turbolink' onto the div containing the link.

It would be nice to somehow disable turbolinks anytime there is a datatable on the page but that seems a little complicated for now since my app is still small.

Comment: I was able to successfully fix the turbolinks issues without having to resort to data-no-turbolink. 

See solution below.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using the `$(document).ready` event to initialize the datatables. When using turbolinks when you click a link this event won't fire because turbolinks loads the page itself. So you should use the `document page:change` event instead. See here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#page-change-events

Answer (score 1):

Just like lunr said, you have to put `$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->` in your .coffee file

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used the following CoffeeScript code to make DataTables work correctly on Rails 5 / Turbolinks 5.

If you use this script, you will no longer have the problem where the DataTables wrapper reloads after you hit the back button on your browser.

Please note that I also am using the [turbolinks-compatibility](http://%20https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/blob/master/src/turbolinks/compatibility.coffee) script.

I'm hopeful this will help someone else who is Googling / struggling with this like I was.

TurboLinks is great for speed ... but it makes loading JavaScript a pain.

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  tableElementIds = [
    '### TABLE ID HERE ###'
  ]
  i = 0
  while i < tableElementIds.length
    tableElementId = tableElementIds[i]
    if $.isEmptyObject($.find(tableElementId))
      i++
      continue
    table = undefined
    if $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable(tableElementId)
      table = $(tableElementId).DataTable()
    else
      table = $(tableElementId).DataTable(### OPTIONS HERE ###)

    document.addEventListener 'turbolinks:before-cache', ->
      table.destroy()
      return

    i++

  return
```